# Django Media images not loading when debug=False

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-staticfiles, django-settings

I can't figure out what went wrong, The project was working fine so I tried to host it on heroku but found some issues with static file, I changed the STATIC_URL in settings.py and then the static files were loading just fine, but the images stored in the database are not visible on the website

My file tree

```
C:.
├───accounts
│   ├───migrations
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   ├───templates
│   └───__pycache__
├───blog
│   ├───archives
│   │   └───templates
│   ├───migrations
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   ├───templates
│   └───__pycache__
├───djago_project
│   └───__pycache__
├───media
│   ├───blog_covers
│   │   └───20
│   │       └───05
│   │           ├───18
│   │           └───19
│   └───images
│       └───blocks
│           └───20
│               └───05
│                   └───18
└───static
    ├───admin
    │   ├───css
    │   │   └───vendor
    │   │       └───select2
    │   ├───fonts
    │   ├───img
    │   │   └───gis
    │   └───js
    │       ├───admin
    │       └───vendor
    │           ├───jquery
    │           ├───select2
    │           │   └───i18n
    │           └───xregexp
    ├───images
    ├───scripts
    └───styles
```

My settings.py file

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static') 
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT =  os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media') 
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

My urls.py file

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('blog.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('accounts/', include('accounts.urls'))
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: This is expected behavior. On production, Django does *not* serve static/media files.